# pandas group_by apply custom calculated values to each group and combine with ungrouped dataframe

Tags: pandas

I have an `analysed_df` like below with date as index

```
              special_number_for_sum       special_number_for_sub
    28-04-25    500                        800
    28-05-01    300                        1200
    28-05-10    100                        400
```

I have another `time_framed_df` with a `datetime` `index` which has multiple rows for a day

```
                        start_price    final_price        sum_with_special        sub_with_special just_date
    2021-04-25 10:30:00   2             5                 None                    None             2021-04-25
    2021-04-25 10:45:00   1             1                 None                    None             2021-04-25
    2021-05-01 10:30:00   5             2                 None                    None             2021-05-01
    2021-05-01 11:30:00   8             1                 None                    None             2021-05-01
    2021-05-10 10:30:00   5             2                 None                    None             2021-05-10
    2021-05-10 10:45:00   7             5                 None                    None             2021-05-10
```

So I want to calculate `sum_with_special` and `sub_with_special` for each day from `analysed_df`

```
#first I grouped timeframed data based on day by using the just_date column for easy grouping for a day

grouped_time_framed_df = time_framed_df.groupby(['just_date'])
```

Then loop through each group and calculate and apply data to the group

```
for time_framed_date, time_framed_df_daily_group in grouped_time_framed_df:
        #first I fetched todays analysis_row
        todays_analysis_row = analysed_df.loc[time_framed_date]
        #here I tried like this but this is replacing all other days values as None and only saving the last 
        looped day
        time_framed_df.loc['sum_with_special'] = time_framed_df.apply(lambda x: x.final_price+todays_analysis_row.special_number_for_sum),axis=1)
        time_framed_df.loc['sub_with_special'] = time_framed_df.apply(lambda x: x.final_price-todays_analysis_row.special_number_for_sub),axis=1)
```

I am having 1 issue & 1 doubt here.

1)Here am getting only the last days calculated values as all other rows in `sum_with_special` & `sub_with_special` columns gets rewrite to `NAN` as am applying inside group. How can I fix this?

2)Is there a way to update both columns or an entire row at the sametime for performance improvement?

Comment: Is `28-04-25` in the `analyze_df`'s index intentionally `2028-04-25`? Or is it a typo?

Comment: @QuangHoang Sorry its a typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think no `groupby` is needed. You can just use `map`:

```
time_frame_df['sum_with_special'] = (time_frame_df.final_price +
 time_frame_df.justdate.map(analyze_df.special_number_for_sum)
)

time_frame_df['sum_with_special'] = (time_frame_df.final_price -
 time_frame_df.justdate.map(analyze_df.special_number_for_sub)
)
```

Comment: Thank you. This is working. But is there a way to update multiple columns together to improve performance?

Comment: @Abhilash as your operations are different for the two columns. I'd say you separate the assignments as in the answer for readability.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for the support. I was overcomplicating things with groupby and all.